# How to support reading from multiple resource paths for localization in MVC core web application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, resx

I am working on a web application where we are using **asp.net MVC core**.

Right now we are supporting 2 languages and we have resource files inside MVC project(for views and other staff) and resources for application service(for enums, error messages, etc) inside separate dll.

Inside startup If I add the following code:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

MVC reads from its resources perfectly but for application service when I use **IStringLocalizer** it cannot find the localized string :

```
stringLocalizer["resource_key"];
```

If I comment the code of AddLocalization above it reads from application resources which are in separate dll but MVC doesn't read from its resources.

My question how to support reading from multiple resource paths?